# Recursively search multiple directories with os.walk()

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

I am trying to walk through a directory and recursively search three sub directories within my parent directory.  This will work:

```
def find_files(fPattern, list_to_append):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\CSVs'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\No_Bath_CSVS'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\Two_Bar_CSVS'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))  
    return list_to_append
```

but its rather clunky.  How do i `os.walk` through mutiple sub directories with out having to hard code them in?

Comment: Why don't you start one level higher?

Comment: If i do that it will only search `c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\CSVs` for my `fPattern`.  It seems like it forgets there are other folders to search.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have those 3 folders in `r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output'` you can os.walk from that folder, otherwise you can remove the extra folder in yours first iteration, like this

case 1, no extra folder

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
        list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

case 2, extra folders

```
my_folders = ['CSVs', 'No_Bath_CSVS', 'Two_Bar_CSVS']
first = True
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output'):
    if first:
        dirnames.clear()
        dirnames.extend(my_folders)
        first = False
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
        list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

manipulations to the `dirnames` yield by [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) affect how you visit the subfolders later on

look what the documentation said about it

> `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)`
>
> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again. Modifying *dirnames* when topdown is `False` has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in *dirnames* are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

You can also redefine your function like this

```
def find_files(fPattern, list_to_append, path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            list_to_append.append(os.path.join(root, filename))  
    return list_to_append
```

here you give the folder you want to work in to your function, then you only need to call it with the folder you want, or define another function that call this one with those folders that way you don't repeat your code without need.

Aditionally, if you always work in that folder you can put that in a global variable like this

```
WORKING_FOLDER = r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output'
```

and only give the folder name relative to that folder, and when you need the absolute path to do something do

```
os.path.join(WORKING_FOLDER, foldername)
```

and define a function like this for example

```
def my_work_in(fPattern, list_to_append, folders):
    result = list_to_append
    for foldername in folders:
        result = find_files(fPattern, result , os.path.join(WORKING_FOLDER, foldername))
    return result
```

and for example call it as

```
result = my_work_in(fPattern, [],  ['CSVs', 'No_Bath_CSVS', 'Two_Bar_CSVS'] )
```

---

Ofcourse you should know that modify the stuff you give to your functions is usually bad practice, so your function really should be

```
def find_files(fPattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))  
    return list_to_append
```

or better yet as a generator

```
def find_files(fPattern, path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, fPattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)
```

in the both cases there is no unwanted modifications and you can use it as

```
result = []
result.extend( find_files(fPattern, r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\CSVs') )
result.extend( find_files(fPattern, r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\No_Bath_CSVS') )
result.extend( find_files(fPattern, r'c:\workspace\Sandbar_Process\csv_output\Two_Bar_CSVS') )
print result
```

for this the generator version is better because you don't lose memory with intermediary results